# subversion exporting file problem while exporting file/dir to unix server

Tags: svn, export

am trying to export the file from SVN repository to our Unix server but after exportation files are being corroupted (a charecter ^M beeing added) and we can not use that file to deploy on test servers.

When he use below export command, export got sucessfull but each file created in UNIX workarea has "^M" charcater at the end end of each line in a each file in the folder

$SVN export -q $PROJECT_BUILDS/$first_new_tag $WORKSPACE/$first_new_tag

This generally happened when we try to FTP a file from Windows to UNIX. New line character in Windows file is converted into ^M character

Answer (score 0):

when you're using a windows svn client and the file has the svn property `svn:eol-style` set to `native`, then the exported file will have windows eols (`CRLF`).

If you want the file to have unix/linux eols, you either have to set the `svn:eol-style` property to `LF`, or use a linux/unix client to do the exporting.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve my problem. I have tried all option native, CRLF, LF & CR but still i m getting same courrpted file with added extra ^M at the end of line. Can you please provide me the exact option to use, I am using below command to export my directory `$SVN export -q $PROJECT_BUILDS/$REL_NO $WORKSPACE/$REL_NO` where `$REL_NO` is my directory name